# php won't upload images?

Tags: php, apache, centos

I have a php script with no erros (I tested it in other servers), the problem is, in this server I cannot upload images from php.

I add 755 to folder, php.ini file upload is on, max file size is 12mb.

I run this:

```
chown apache /var/www/html/img-img/
chmod 755 /var/www/html/img-img/
```

but also didn't solve my problem.

my php also try to create a folder to upload images inside img-img (no success):

```
 $pasta = date("dmy");
 $pasta_dir2 = "img-img/$pasta";
 if(!file_exists($pasta_dir2)){
  mkdir($pasta_dir2, 0755);
 }
```

I have this warnings:

```
move_uploaded_file(img-img/14719222_886454304825512_8860750091242176512_n.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/teste.php on line 38, referer: http://example.com/teste2.php 
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phptZYSam' to 'img-img/14719222_886454304825512_8860750091242176512_n.jpg' in /var/www/html/teste.php on line 38, referer: http://example.com/teste2.php
```

any ideas how to solve this without break server security?

Comment: Those aren't "warnings".  Those are *errors*.  Fix the permissions problem :)

Comment: @paulsm4 how to fix that? I tried almost everything...

Comment: Is your web server actually running under the `apache` user? If not, then your `chown` was wrong.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I think it is. it is a lamp in centos...

Comment: You should probably make sure. If it's not running as `apache`, then what you have is not going to work. And you're trying to figure out why it's not working. So ruling out that possibility would seem useful.

Comment: @GregSchmidt it is apache, the user.

Comment: Okay. On my dev server, which is also CentOS, it runs under the `www` user. But it can be whatever user you set in the `httpd.conf`, so worth asking, I think.

Comment: Have you tried it using the full path instead of a relative path starting with `img-img`?

Comment: @GregSchmidt for sure! it is `User apache
Group apache`. I haven't try that. with this command any folder I create inside img-img will have the same user/permissions as img-img? because php will create folders there with data to locate images...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solve my problem:
I don't know what it does, but works... if anyone knows, please, answer this and let me know.

```
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/img-img -R
```

Comment: Hmmm - that's the LAST thing I would have thought of.  Good catch! [chcon](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chcon) is an SELinux command.  FYI, SELinux "locks down" the security on a *nix host.  That's a Good Thing ... but learning to use SELinux effectively isn't trivial.  For DEV boxes, I just disable it: 1) `sudo vi /etc/selinux/config`, then edit the line `SELINUX=disabled`. 2) Save and reboot.

Comment: PS: Please "accept" your answer, when you get a chance.

Comment: @paulsm4 thank you very much, friend! yeah, that was hard to guess! but it was what I nedeed! haha thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Check if img-img folder exist and try to set 744 permission to all the folders and subfolders of html using `chmod -R 0755 /var/www/html/`

Comment: thanks for your answer, I just tried it and still not uploading ;/

Comment: thanks friend, I could make it work with a strange `chcon` command xD